# Remapping keys using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use autohotkey to remap the f11 key and the combination ctrl+f11 to something easier accessibele as ctrl+left and ctrl+down.

I tried the following code, but it runs both f11 and ctrl+f11 if I type one of the key hotkeys. I also tried doing the same using the Send command, but then the second hotkey wouldn't work.

```
>^Left::F11
Return
>^Down::^F11
Return
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use the rebinding syntax `key1::key2`, but it should be used only for single keys.
Use normal `Send` instead:

```
>^Left::
    send {F11}
return

>^Down::
    send ^{F11}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
^Left::F11
^Down::^F11
```

Comment: Can it be that it "remembers" me pressing ctrl, when I press ctrl + left that it first sends a f11 and then a ctrl+f11?

Comment: Not likely - that would be a bug in AHK.